# Adding chartmouselistener() to jfreechart in java

Tags: java, user-interface, jfreechart

I want to add `chartmouselistener()` to some specific point of [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartLineChartDemo6.htm) graph like in (1,1),(2,4),(3,3) and so on and print something.

I don't want `mouselistener()` for the whole panel. `mouselistener()` will  work only when I will click on predefined point.

Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to add a ChartMouseListener to the whole panel and then call ChartMouseEvent.getEntity() to figure out which point was clicked.